# How do you have mouseover and a link at the same time?

Tags: css, hyperlink, mouseover

Example Page: http://kian02.comlu.com/kian3.html
I want the Navi in the example page to have mouseover and also be a link.
It's been going crazy as a result of me trying as you can see lol.

Comment: example link not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a tag and href to the link on mouseover will also work and link also work

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to re-work your code to make this navigation more useable.

A good way to do it is to use an unordered list with list elements and anchors:

```
<ul id="navigation">
  <li><a href="home.htm">Home</li>
  <li><a href="contact.htm">Contact</li>
  <li><a href="gallery.htm">Gallery</li>
</ul>
```

Then use CSS to display the elements inline and add hover styles:

```
#navigation li
{
    display: inline /*this will display your elements horizontally*/
    color: #fff;
    background-image: url(path/to/file.png);
}

#navigation li:hover
{
    color: #f00;
}
```

You should also take a look at [CSS sprites](http://www.google.no/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=css+sprites), they're very very useful with navigation menus, and will definitely help you here to make your navigation look and work as you want :)